# Android more option menus ain't appearing as grid

Tags: java, android

I have around 10 or 12 option menus, when I press the menu key, 6 menus appear as a grid including More, but when clicking More menu, the rest of menus appear as list. How can I make them look like a grid too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [creating custom menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way), this helped me a lot. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Android API (10 and below) only supports 6 menu button items, after that it adds the "More" button as you noticed. (API 11+ recommends using an ActionBar, not an options menu.) I don't know of anyway to change the Android code to display more items in the grid.  But you could write your own code to do what you want.

From the [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu):

> If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x (API level 10) or lower, the contents of your options menu appear at the bottom of the screen when the user presses the Menu button, as shown in figure 1. When opened, the first visible portion is the icon menu, which holds up to six menu items. If your menu includes more than six items, Android places the sixth item and the rest into the overflow menu, which the user can open by selecting More.